# Socket programming: How a socket client may discover server IP address inside LAN?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

**Scope:**

- OS: MACOS, Windows;
- Language: C++Boost library;

**Description:**

LAN has `N` computers with *MacOS* and *Windows* operating systems, where `N ≈ 10`. The IP addresses of the computer are not static and assigned by the network. On one of these computers *(machine S)* a socket server application is running. And on another machine *(machine C)* a client socket application is running. This is not a static setup, and next time it might be different computers with different IP addresses.

**Update:**

a server machine -- is a slave. A client machine is a master. A user can install client software in any computer in LAN, and server software in any other computer in LAN. Server take responsibility for the calculations which takes a lot of resources and just send a result to a client. So, the main idea is: a user of a master computer should not provide a server IP address, but the client soft should be able to discover it by itself.

**Task:**  Client socket application does not know Server application IP address, and should be able to discover it.
Solution should be a cross-platform one (*Boost C++*)

Please suggest the best practices.

My best guess was: retrieve all the IP addresses of connected devices and `socket->send_async_to` them. And if I get answer in `handle_receive` callback -- this is a server app. But I did not find a way how to get all the IP addresses of LAN devices.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and ideas.

Comment: `My best guess was: retrieve all the IP addresses of connected devices` that is probably a bad idea what if a computer on the LAN happens to have a socket open on the same port as you expect?

Comment: The question itself is a bit off-topic because it is either too broad (not asking about a specific problem a tool/library) you use or asking for a library tool. Having that said you probably are looking for something like mDNS/Zeroconfig.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the OP is trying to achieve. The title seems to ask about about getting the IP of a *specific* server - but w/o providing information what the specific thing about the server is. The approach provided in the body seems to determined to find *all* servers in the network. And it is unclear if this is about purely client-side only discovery or if one can expect common discovery protocols to exist for the server, i.e. plain DNS, mDNS, DNS SRV records, directory services ...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich a server machine -- is a slave. A client machine is a master. A user can install client software in any computer in LAN, and server software in any other computer in LAN. Server take responsibility for the calculations which takes a lot of resources and just send a result to a client. So, the main idea is: a user of a master computer should not provide a server IP address, but the client soft should be able to discover it by itself.

Comment: @t.niese it says that: I did not find a way how to get all the IP addresses of LAN devices. With Boost C++.

Comment: @Dmitry: So you have full control of both how client and server are implemented, but no control of where they are installed in the same LAN and not control over infrastructure like centralized DNS? In this case have a look at [Zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) which includes various forms of service discovery. A common concept here is not to scan the network like you propose but instead to use [broadcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)), i.e. single packets send to specific broadcasts addr which all receive.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. I think this is one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use UDP to send request to all the computers in the network.Write a thread in server to respond udp request. then you can get response from the server and get the socket ip.

Comment: That is what is wrote in the question: But I did not find a way how to get all the IP addresses of LAN devices.

Comment: write small application for server to respond udp for particular port. for example any request from udp port 1000 like "hi are you server?", then send response to "yes i am". Now add discovery code in client to send udp broadcast with message "hi are you server?" and wait for response. Server only respond for your request.